# Word-wrapping in the R environment for Windows

Tags: windows, r, customization

(Asking this on behalf of a member of our Bay Area R Group.  I did not have a ready answer as I run ESS within Emacs.  I assume this question refers to running R within the command-line environment that ships in the standard Windows distribution).

I'm new to R, but what I've found in searching for my answer is that there isn't anything about customizing R so that I can work faster.

One of my main problems is the lack of word wrapping in my version running on Windows XP. I noticed that my friends with the Mac OS have word wrapping.

Is there a way to enable word wrapping in R running on a Windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue happens with long strings.  Here I create a character vector:

```
> z <- "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

Then, on Windows, depending on the display size, it will look like this:

```
> z
[1] "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz$
```

With a $ sign at the end.  Setting the width option has no effect for a long character vector.  In fact, in the Windows GUI, by default it sets the option(width) automatically on resize.

I don't believe that there are any global options to address this.  You might try using the strwrap() function.

```
> strwrap(z, width=60)
[1] "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"   "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"   
[3] "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"   "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
```

Answer (score 2):

Shane points out that this does not work on the Windows R application, so I'm marking this as CW in case someone on another platform stumbles across this question.

---

I don't have Windows handy to try it on, but you might be able to use `options(width=XXX)` to accomplish word-wrap.

```
> rnorm(20)
 [1]  1.5096142  2.5213651  1.6129801  1.2328282  0.1099109  0.7681205
 [7]  0.7408279  0.1853688  0.2679453 -1.4006292  0.5178583 -0.8838526
[13] -1.5162541 -1.5603825 -0.7217159  2.3466593  0.7382550  1.6618710
[19]  1.3201585  0.2872295
> options(width=50)
> rnorm(20)
 [1] -0.990605829 -1.479986280 -0.670011156
 [4]  1.545288381  1.749429922 -0.386976121
 [7]  0.152663018  0.537898605  0.307018436
[10] -1.214402678 -0.066987719 -0.003181806
[13]  0.775656734 -1.084597991  1.419298825
[16]  1.634812239 -0.234720361 -1.232159240
[19] -0.560096460  0.167267767
```

And here's the R help for options, for reference:

> 'width': controls the maximum number
>   of columns on a line used in
>    printing vectors, matrices and arrays, and when filling by
>   'cat'.
>
> Columns are normally the same as characters except in CJK
>   languages.
>
> You may want to change this if you re-size the window that R
>   is running in.  Valid values are 10...10000 with default
>   normally 80.  (The limits on valid values are in file
>   'Print.h' and can be changed by re-compiling R.)  Some R
>   consoles automatically change the value when they are
>   resized.

Comment: The windows console automatically changes this when it's resized.

Answer (score 0):

Well I tried the same, but the component they use in Windows GUI obviously does not have that feature. Where was the word wrapping option in the Mac menu ?